# Resize/show/hide adview from another view

Tags: android, layout, resize, admob

Iam developing a simple game that it has some gamestates (paused, playing, playerlost, etc...). And iam trying show a adview(admob) like that:

```
paused -> Show ad as banner.
playerlost -> show as fullscreen.
playing -> hide the ad.
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    private tGame game;
    //(...)
    layout.addView(game);
    layout.addView(admob, adParams);
    setContentView(layout);
    //(...)
}
```

Another view (tGame):

```
public class tGame extends View implements Runnable{
    //(...)
    int gameState = 0; // <- PLAYING, PAUSED, PLAYERLOST, etc.
    //(...)
}
```

How i can resize the ad(admob) from another view(game)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the visibility flags to show/hide the ad and launch an interstitial ad for fullscreen ads:

```
if(paused)
  adview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
else if(playerlost)
 interstitialAd.show();
else if(playing)
  adview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

**UPDATE:**

To modify the ad from another class, you can use a facade:

Define an interface for example MyAdListener.java:

```
public interface MyAdListener{
public void showAd();
public void hideAd();
public void lauchFullScreenAd();
}
```

In your game's main activity, implement the interface:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements MyAdListener{
    private tGame game;
    //(...)
    layout.addView(game);
    layout.addView(admob, adParams);
    setContentView(layout);
//(...)

@Override
public void showAd(){
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run(){
      adview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   }
  );
 }

@Override
public void hideAd(){
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run(){
      adview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   }
  );

}



 @Override
    public void launchFullScreenAd(){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run(){
          if (interstitial != null) interstitial.show();    
       }
      );
     }


}
```

Then finally in your game's class:

```
public class tGame extends View implements Runnable{
    MyAdListener myAdListener;
    public tGame(Context context){
    myAdListener = (MyAdListener)context;
    }
    //(...)
    int gameState = 0; // <- PLAYING, PAUSED, PLAYERLOST, etc.
    //(...)

   if(paused)
      myAdListener.showAd();
    else if(playerlost)
      myAdListener.launchFullScreenAd();
    else if(playing)
      myAdListener.hideAd();

}
```

Comment: Ok, but game states variables (paused, playing, etc.) are in a different class.

Comment: You can make them static variables and access them in your main activity (where the ads are defined). Let me know if you need assistance with that :)

Comment: Okay. You can use a listener to achieve that. Just make sure you make the calls in the UI thread using the runOnUIThread() method. Check my updated answer